# Python: Displaying variable with multiple xml tags inside message box

Tags: python, xml, variables, xml-parsing, easygui

I've been working on a script for a couple of days that will retrieve tags inside an XML file and output their values to a message box. Originally I was going to use Tkinter but I noticed that it would only print one set of tags, so I tried using easygui and I had the same problem.

I have quite a bit of experience with programming but I'm newer to python, I did several searches on google but nothing turned up so I thought I'd ask here.

Here's the part of the code that's acting up.

```
# Import our modules here.
import easygui as eg
import lxml.etree as etree

# Get our XML file here.
doc = etree.parse('file.xml')

# Grab the item tag and display the child tags name, description, and status.    
for item in doc.getiterator('item'):
    item_name = item.findtext('name')
    item_desc = item.findtext('description')
    item_status = item.findtext('status')

    # Create a variable that adds the above child tags together.
    print_xml = str((item_name + " | " + item_desc + " | " + item_status))

# Create message box to display print_xml.
    eg.msgbox(print_xml, title="XML Reader")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? You've shown some code and say it's "acting up". What does that mean? It's also not clear what you mean when you say that tkinter would only print one set of tags -- tkinter has no such limitation.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. By tags I was meaning XML tags. Only one combination of the tags name, description, and status is displayed at a time and I'm trying to get all of the name, description, and status tags displayed into one message box. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That last line of yours:   eg.msgbox(...) is indented at the same level as the lines within your 'item' loop.  So, it is executed for each entry.

If you want all entries displayed at once, create a list of entries inside that loop, then combine that list into a string. outside of the loop

The following code is similar to yours except that I used a different .xml schema so needed to change it a bit.

```
import easygui as eg
import lxml.etree as etree

# Get our XML file here.
# From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
doc = etree.parse('books.xml')

# Grab the item tag and display the child tags name, description, and status.
for catalog in doc.getiterator('catalog'):
    books = list()
    for item in catalog.getiterator('book'):
        item_name = item.findtext('title')
        item_desc = item.findtext('description')
        item_status = item.findtext('publish_date')

        # Create a variable that adds the above child tags together.
        books.append('{0} | {1} | {2}'.format(item_name, item_desc, item_status))

    # Create message box to display print_xml.
    eg.msgbox('\n'.join(books), title="XML Reader")
```

Note the creation of a list called 'books' to hold what you called print_xml.  That list is .appended to.  Finally '\n'.join(books) is used to convert that list into a string with newlines separating each item.